# Cannot load libvulkan.so on Linux chroot running on Android while normal Android apps can load it

Tags: android, linux, shared-object

## Environment

First I will give a quick summary of my environment

Device: Samsung Galaxy M20 (m20lte)
SoC: [Exynos 7904](https://semiconductor.samsung.com/processor/mobile-processor/exynos-7-series-7904/) (with Mali-G71 GPU)
OS: Android 10 (Stock ROM with root using [Magisk](https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/))
Kernel: 4.4.177
SELinux is disabled (set to permissive mode)
Vulkan API version: 1.1.108

Chroot environment: Debian 11 (arm64) running on [Linux Deploy](https://github.com/meefik/linuxdeploy), with full root access. Directories like `/dev`, `/proc`, `/data`, `/system`, `/sdcard` are mounted into the chroot.

## Vulkan availability

I know this device support Vulkan API (Vulkan loader avaliable at `/system/lib64/libvulkan.so`).

Normal Android apps can load and use Vulkan APIs without any problems. For example:

- [Vulkan Caps Viewer](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/VulkanCapsViewer) can display Vulkan information on this device
- GeekBench 5, `Compute` section has an option to compute with GPU using Vulkan API, and it works well

## Problem

I cannot load `libvulkan.so` from `/system/lib64/libvulkan.so` by running program in the chroot.

For example, I created a simple c source (named `dlopen.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
        void *handle = dlopen("libvulkan.so", RTLD_LAZY);
        if (!handle) {
                printf("Cannot load libvulkan.so\n");
        } else {
                printf("Loaded libvulkan.so\n");
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Compile it using gcc: `gcc dlopen.c -ldl -o dlopentest`
Setup the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/system/lib64/` or symlink `/system/lib64/libvulkan.so` to (folder in chroot) `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so` and `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so.1`
Finally run it using `./dlopentest`, the program always print `Cannot load libvulkan.so`

Using `strace`, but nothing weird found ([log link](https://gist.github.com/raspiduino/32a35cee634a4ef33208ec11485ecac6#file-strace1-txt))

I'm not sure about `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so`, since instead of being a symlink to `libc.so.6` or a real `.so` file, it's some kind of ld script. But replacing it with a symlink to `libc.so.6` makes no change.

`vulkaninfo` also reports an error:

```
ERROR at /build/vulkan-tools-3Ouhix/vulkan-tools-1.2.162.0+dfsg1/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:628: Failed to initialize: Vulkan loader is not installed, not found, or failed to load.
```

`strace` result is pretty much the same as my `dlopentest`, so I won't include it here.

## EDIT 1:

(actually I don't know what section to put this, so I put it here)

Running `file` on `/system/lib64/libvulkan.so`:

```
/system/lib64/libvulkan.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=e749d3c10d92fcef9b84402783d311f8, stripped
```

It's `dynamically linked`, so I run `ldd` on it and notice the following line:

```
/system/lib64/libvulkan.so: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so: version `LIBC' not found (required by /system/lib64/libvulkan.so)
/system/lib64/libvulkan.so: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so: version `LIBC' not found (required by /system/lib64/libvulkan.so)
```

And other lines from `.so` libraries in `/system/lib64` claimed the same thing.

So I check the `/system/lib64/libc.so`, and found that it's a symbolic link to `/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so`.

So I mounted `/apex/com.android.runtime` to chroot.

After doing so, ldd found no more problem ([log link](https://gist.github.com/raspiduino/32a35cee634a4ef33208ec11485ecac6#file-ldd1-txt))

But, when I run the program:

```
root@localhost:~# ./dlopentest
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

Running `strace` ([log link](https://gist.github.com/raspiduino/32a35cee634a4ef33208ec11485ecac6#file-strace2-txt))

Using `gdb`, I found that it was a trap signal from `/system/lib64/ld-android.so`

```
Program received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x0000007fb7fef000 in rtld_db_dlactivity () from /system/lib64/ld-android.so
```

When I check that file:

```
root@localhost:~# file /system/lib64/ld-android.so
/system/lib64/ld-android.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[md5/uuid]=62f4de8cdef6f71d65c403ac59427c51, stripped
root@localhost:~# ldd /system/lib64/ld-android.so
        statically linked
```

## Question

- Why it does not work (why I cannot load `libvulkan.so` properly)?
- How to fix it?

## Real purpose

I know this section might not related to the question, but I still want to include it, to avoid possible XY problem.

I want to run [War Thunder](https://warthunder.com/en) (a game, and it supports x86_64 Linux). I run it on [box64](https://github.com/ptitSeb/box64) and it runs until report cannot initialize Vulkan. FYI, Vulkan is the only supported render backend for the game on Linux, so I can't use OpenGL or something.

The game require the real libc (not Android one), so I can't run it on proot, and distro-proof on Termux is too complicated compared to Linux Deploy.

Finally, thank you for reading this
I just want to run War Thunder :)

Comment: Ok, I think this crash because `/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` is loaded, then another libc `/system/lib64/libc.so` is loaded. I don't think libc can be loaded with multiple instances

Comment: Possible solution: 1) (unlikely) If we can call vulkan api from vulkan kernel driver without using Android libs, then write a simple vulkan loader than redirect the calls. 2) Write a "Vulkan server" that create an IPC (pipeline), read Vulkan commands from that pipeline, then calls to Android's libvulkan.so, then compile it using Android NDK. Then write a "client" libvulkan.so that communicate through the IPC to redirect the calls from program. Compile it using gcc in chroot.